# how to stop auto adjustment of WPF Datagrid columns width on mouse double click on datagrid header

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using wpf datagrids with multiple columns. i have assigned them widths by using ratios or u can say by using * signs. so that they can adjust themselves according to available space.

```
                  <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="3*"/>

                        <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
```

now when i change column width on runtime using mouse drag and then i double click on header the grid column widths  auto adjust themselves.

can any one plz tell me how to stop this auto adjustments on mouse double click

Comment: Why do you want to let the user change size via dragging, but not via doubleclick?

Comment: coz by dragging he can adjust column according to his need but by double click wpf reneder column width automatically and arbitrarily which is not acceptable

Comment: It's not arbitrarily, but a common conventention among DataGrids everywhere, most notably Excel. I would strongly advise against disabling it, because most users expect it to work. Ultimatly it's your decision of course, and user expectations vary with the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know why you want this, but you can use the PreviewMouseDoubleClick event and set e.Handled=true if someone click on the the header.